# ASIO driver not producing sound (cant figure this out, plz help)

Tags: studio, asio

I'm loading Fruity Loops 10 and everything checks out fine except for the fact that I can only use the primary sound driver (the one that always lags). When I load ASIO it loads up but it won't make any sound. Now I know that I should have other windows that use sound closed when I do this... but it's just not working. I'm not very experienced with sound drivers, I just know which ones I should use for low latency and that's pretty much the extent of my knowledge of sound drivers.

tl;dr - ASIO wont work when i load it in FL even though i have nothing else open in the background

Comment: did you try http://www.image-line.com/support/FLHelp/html/envsettings_asio4all.htm ?

Comment: Did that support link answer your question? If so, please post an answer explaining what you did and why that fixed it :)

Comment: No, I went through the entire thing and not one of them worked =\

Comment: Finally found the answer @WarriorBob you can close this question (thanks!)

Comment: @Daniel Please post what you did to solve it! Closing the question would miss the point of the site, which is to share knowledge.

Comment: @WarriorBob here it is, i followed this troubleshooting vid and ended up with working ASIO drivers. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbabtLVeP5Q